# ListView слушатель события

Tags: java, android, json, listview

Приходит json в `ListView` с именами. тег, имя и т.д.
По нажатию на имя надо вывести его в `TextView`. Все работает, только выводит не имя а `{teg = name}`
Как сделать, чтобы выводилось только `name`?

```
try {
    dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray friends = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("friends");


    for (int i = 0; i < friends.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject secondFriend = friends.getJSONObject(i);

        //JSONObject contacts = friend.getJSONObject("contacts");

        String id = secondFriend.getString("name");

        // Создание нового HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Добавление каждого дочернего узла в значение HashMap key => value
        map.put("name", id);

        // Добавление HashList в ArrayList
        UploadsList.add(map);

        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Main2Activity.this, UploadsList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name"}, new int[]{R.id.name});

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String xx = parent.getAdapter().getItem((int) id).toString();
         text.setText(xx);

            }
        });
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

лучше использовать ArrayList сущностей friend (id, name) вместо HashMap.
и тогда все будет проще сделать

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,  int position, long id) {
    textview.setText(UploadsList.get(position).getName());
  }
});
```